# Format date ingredient in IFTTT channel

Tags: if-this-then-that

I'm trying to create a recipe similar to [this one](https://ifttt.com/recipes/146) where I record all of my Foursquare check-ins on a particular day to a single note for that day in Evernote.

Unfortunately, the `{{CheckinDate}}` ingredient uses time as well as date (Example: `April 29, 2013 at 12:01PM`). What I need is *just* the date (`April 29, 2013`).

So, I can have a separate note for every check-in (by using the date), or have [*all* Foursquare check-ins written to a single note](https://ifttt.com/recipes/37334) (until it fills up and creates a new note). Neither of which is what I want.

Is there a way to get all Foursquare check-ins on a particularly calendar date to be in one Evernote note?

---

I thought about using my [Foursquare RSS feed](https://foursquare.com/feeds/) the but `{{EntryPublished}}` ingredient is formatted the same way (with the time).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I contacted IFTTT support and they told me that this is currently not possible (within IFTTT) but that they'll take it as feedback for future enhancements.

So, the answer would appear to be "you can't".

I'd love to see some ideas for alternatives using a third-party solution.

Comment: 6 years later and we still cant format dates. -_-

Answer (score 1):

In 2021, IFTTT supports the use of building applets with "filter code", namely using filter code, you have access to `Meta.currentUserTime`, which should allow you to grab whatever format of date/time you want and replace the `{{CheckinDate}}` with that value, passing it along to the next action. I'm doing something similar with Spotify, where a previously supported method must've been deprecated in April 2021... I had an applet that added newly liked tracks to a custom playlist for that month & year. Since it stopped working, I'm building a new one from scratch. Found this particular post, which didn't quite help me, but then I also found the IFTTT KB about filter code, https://help.ifttt.com/hc/en-us/articles/360052451954, which seems to get me what I need. Basically, I formatted the output of `Meta.currentUserTime` and then passed the variable along to next step:

```
// Format the Display of the date/time value and save it to a variable
let playlistTitle = Meta.currentUserTime.format('MMMM YYYY');

// Pass the previously created variable to the command
Spotify.addATrackToAPlaylist.setPlaylist(playlistTitle)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the most important part of your recipe is record all check-ins to a single note.
So maybe change title format by hand per week is an acceptable solution.

Answer (score -3):

`{{EntryPublished}}` is for the date of the publication.

Comment: {{EntryPublished}} is not available as an ingredient from the Foursquare channel.

Comment: As for the RSS feed, {{EntryPublished}} is still in the format `August 23, 2010 at 11:01PM`.